# Downloading a Few Seconds of Audio from a Youtube Video with ffmpeg and youtube-dl Results in [youtube]: No such file or directory error

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Below is the program that I wrote:

```
ffmpeg -ss 60 -t 10 -i $(youtube-dl -f 140 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDCk3hLIVXo) output.mp3
```

This is supposed to get 10 seconds of audio starting at the one minute mark of the video and write it to output.mp3. If I run the youtube-dl command separately, and then the ffmpeg command with the entire video audio as input, it works. But, I do not want to download the entire video as well as create a new file with only a few seconds of audio.

In its current state, I am getting [youtube]: No such file or directory errors. Does anyone know how I can fix this and keep it in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the output which is returned from `youtube-dl` is several lines of information, so `ffmpeg` doesn't know how to deal with it properly.

You'll want to return the actual name of the file without any other information included; a tool like `awk` or `sed` can be helpful for this. In addition there will need to be an encoding step added at the end so the audio stream gets copied to the output file (`libmp3lame`->`mp3`).

**Example**:

```
ffmpeg -ss 60 -t 10 $(youtube-dl -f 140 -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDCk3hLIVXo | \
sed "s/.*/-i &/") -c:v copy -codec:a libmp3lame output.mp3
```

This command should return an audio `mp3` file 60 seconds in which is 10 seconds in duration.

**Result**:

```
output.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1,  64 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also produces the original file... do you know how I can suppress the creation of the original file, or do I need to just delete it afterwords?

Comment: Thanks so much! I really need to start learning some of the more sophisticated commands :P